# Coffeescript on click event not firing?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project where clicking a `link_to` element on my view is supposed to trigger a method in my CoffeeScript, but the output is never printed!

This is the relevant part of my HTML (the link works):

```
<%= link_to 'Start Quiz!', {:controller => :pages, :action => :start_quiz}, :id => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg', :method => :get %>
```

This is the method in my ActionCable CoffeeScript file:

```
App.quiz_data = App.cable.subscriptions.create "QuizDataChannel",
  connected: ->
    console.log "[AC] on click handler called?"
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', -> $('btn btn-primary btn-lg').on 'click', -> console.log "[AC] on click handler called!")
```

**My console reads "[AC] on click handler called?" but nothing else, even after I click on the link.**

I've been googling a lot and a few posts suggested the problem might be with turbolinks. The above code already reflects 2 of several solutions I've tried (specifying get method in link, enclosing event handler with `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', -> ...)`), none of which fixed it for me. I'm a Rails beginner and have no clue about CoffeeScript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After adding the id selector # and deleting the get method in the `link_to` element and `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', -> ...)` in the event handler - it finally works! :D

HTML element now:

```
<%= link_to 'Start Quiz!', {:controller => :pages, :action => :start_quiz}, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg', :id => 'start_quiz_button' %>
```

CoffeeScript file now:

```
App.quiz_data = App.cable.subscriptions.create "QuizDataChannel",
  connected: ->
    console.log "[AC] on click handler called?"
    $('#start_quiz_button').on 'click', -> console.log "[AC] on click handler called!"
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: What are you expecting the `'btn btn-primary btn-lg'` selector to match?

Comment: the id of the `link_to` element I posted - is that incorrect @mu?

Comment: (1) id-selectors use `#`. (2) `'btn btn-primary btn-lg'` looks like a class list, not an id. (3) Some time reading the [jQuery selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) might be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, it used to be a class for my css and on my many tries to fix the problem I had sometime just changed it to an id. I've added a # now, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to change your id to a valid one (read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)), something like `start_quizz_button`

2) Use an id-selector `#` :

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', -> $('#start_quizz_button').on 'click', -> console.log "[AC] on click handler called!")
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I've changed it to what you suggested, but "[AC] on click handler called!" is still not printed when I click the button :( I'd be grateful for any other pointers as to what might be the problem.

Comment: Nvm, I deleted both of the above mentioned turbolinks fixes and now it works - Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please upvote my answer  if it solved your problem